# Is there a size 2 generating set of the signed symmetric group $B_n$?

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

The signed symmetric group $B_n$ is a permutation group where the underlying set is $B_n=\{\sigma \in S_{A_n}| \forall x \in A_n, \sigma(-x)= -\sigma(x)\}$ with $A_n=\{-n,-(n-1),-(n-2),\cdots,-1,1,\cdots, n-1,n\}$.

$B_n$ can be generated by the 3 permutations  $(1,2)(-1,-2) ; (1,2,\cdots, n)(-1,-2,\cdots, -n)$ and $(-i,i)$ for some $i$.

Is there a generating set of $B_n$ with only 2 elements?

Comment: Have you tried to check explicitly for some small values of $n$?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. Take two $a,b$ generators of $S_n$, where $b$ has odd order and fixes point $1$. For example, if $n$ is even, let $a=(1,2)$, $b=(2,3,\ldots,n)$. If $n$ is odd let $a=(1,2,3,4)$, $b=(3,4,\ldots,n)$.

Let $\bar{a},\bar{b}$ be their natural images$^\dagger$ in $B_n$. Then $B_n = \langle \bar{a}, \bar{b}(1,-1) \rangle$. This is because $\bar{b}$ and $(-1,1)$ commiute and have coprime order, so both $\bar{b}$ and $(-1,1)$ are powers of $\bar{b}(-1,1)$ and hence $\langle \bar{a}, \bar{b}(1,-1) \rangle=\langle \bar{a}, \bar{b},(1,-1) \rangle =B_n$.

$\dagger$ : For a permutation $\alpha$ of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ let $\alpha'$ be the permutation of $\{-1,-2,\ldots,-n\}$ defined by $\alpha(-i) := -\alpha(i)$ for $1 \le i \le n$. By the natural embeddding $S_n \to B_n$ I mean the map defined by $\alpha \mapsto \alpha\alpha'$.

Comment: Please what do you mean by natural image?

Comment: $B_n$ is a semidirect product $N \rtimes S_n$, where $|N|=2^n$. This defines a natural embedding $S_n \to B_n$. I have provides it properly in the edited answer.

Comment: If I understand, with the example you provided, when $n$ is even, $\bar{a}=(1,2)(-1,-2)$, $\bar{b}=(2,3,\ldots,n)(-2,-3,\ldots,-n)$. and if $n$ is odd $\bar{a}=(1,2,3,4)(-1,-2,-3,-4)$, $\bar{b}=(3,4,\ldots,n)(-3,-4,\ldots,-n)$. is that correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Comment: When considering the special case $n=3$ it seems impossible to find $a$ and $b$, generators of $S_3$ such that $b$ both has and odd order and fixes point $1$.  does that mean $B_3$ cannot be generated by two elements?

Comment: No it doesn't mean that $B_3$ is not $2$-generated. It just means that you need a different argument. I will leave that to you.

Answer (score 7):

Yes. See proposition 6 in this paper: ["The strong symmetric genus of the hyperoctahedral groups"](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0309388) for a recipe of how to find a pair of generators.